D3D11 How to properly copy from swap_chain/render target
I've been trying to write a function that simply takes the backbuffer/framebuffer and saves its contents to a file.
internal unsigned char *r_get_backbuffer(Arena *arena, GFX_Window *window, int width, int height)
{
  D3D11_Window *w = d3d11_window_from_opaque(window);
            
  int bytes = width*height*4;
  result = arena_push_array(arena, u8, bytes); // @Note: This just allocates memory

  ID3D11Texture2D *surface = 0;
  w->swap_chain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (void **) &surface);

  D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc = {0};
  desc.ArraySize = 1;
  desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
  desc.Width = width;
  desc.Height = height;
  desc.MipLevels = 1;
  desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
  desc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
  desc.BindFlags = 0;
  desc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
  desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;

  ID3D11Texture2D *tex = 0;
  d3d11_state.device->CreateTexture2D(&desc, 0, &tex);
  d3d11_state.context->CopyResource(tex, surface);
                
  D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE texture_resource = {0};
  d3d11_state.context->Map(tex, 0, D3D11_MAP_READ, 0, &texture_resource);
  MemoryCopy(result, texture_resource.pData, bytes); // @Note: Just a wrapper for memcpy()
  d3d11_state.context->Unmap(tex, 0);
                    
  tex->Release();
  surface->Release();
}

The above function works well for sizes that are specifically 16:9: 1280x720 image
However there's a problem when size is anything else:
1000x1000 image
This makes me think that CopyResource(); call (or similar) adds some of its own padding?
I'm using stb image write for the image writing and my call looks like so:
int w = 1000;
int h = 1000;
u8 *pixels = r_get_backbuffer(frame_arena, window, w, h);
stbi_write_jpg("ss.jpg", w, h, 4, pixels, w*4);
// ...

Is there something I'm missing? I thought that it might be an issue with 'stride' but no matter what I try it won't budge. I might have missed something in the docs, I've been trying to find an answer for a couple days now and google isn't really helpful nowadays because of its own bloat.
An ideal solution would copy the contents of swap chain/render target view into an array of bytes (color values) properly no matter the size. I don't really care about the specific implementation, I just want to be able to save framebuffer to a file or get its contents as an array of pixels.

Indded, in general, you can't really copy image buffer like that, you must take the stride into account (aka pitch, rowpitch, etc.) and copy row by row https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/image-stride you say you tried but your code doesn't demonstrate it or please paste a fully reproducing code

I'm sorry, when I said I experimented with the stride I meant the actual stride in stbi_write_jpg(); call. I tried accessing RowPitch from texture_resource but to no avail. The above code actually reproduces the issue I'm having, window contents are not properly copied, I also read something about using GDI but couldn't find any decent example.

The code you show is not a "reproducing" code, it's just pieces of c++ that we cannot use to reproduce the problem

Terribly sorry for any confusion, I'm going to leave the answer here in case someone else has a similar problem (assuming google is being helpful). My issue was indeed with the stride, I was copying from the texture (whose stride was RowPitch) to my buffer of pixels (whose stride was width*4). Here's the working code just for copying from the texture:
internal unsigned char *r_get_backbuffer(Arena *arena, GFX_Window *window, int width, int height)
{
  D3D11_Window *w = d3d11_window_from_opaque(window);
            
  int bytes = width*height*4;
  result = arena_push_array(arena, u8, bytes); // @Note: This just allocates memory

  ID3D11Texture2D *surface = 0;
  w->swap_chain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (void **) &surface);

  D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc = {0};
  surface->GetDesc(&desc);
  desc.BindFlags = 0;
  desc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ | D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
  desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;

  ID3D11Texture2D *tex = 0;
  d3d11_state.device->CreateTexture2D(&desc, 0, &tex);
  d3d11_state.context->CopyResource(tex, surface);
                
  D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE texture_resource = {0};
  d3d11_state.context->Map(tex, 0, D3D11_MAP_READ, 0, &texture_resource);

  // @Note: This part was incorrect previously, now corrected
  u8 *dst = result;
  u8 *src = ((u8 *) texture_resource.pData);
  for (s32 i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
    MemoryCopy(dst, src, width*4);
    dst += width*4;
    src += texture_resource.RowPitch;
  }
  // ==============

  d3d11_state.context->Unmap(tex, 0);
                    
  tex->Release();
  surface->Release();
}

